# Divide and Difference Between Two TextBoxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I want to get difference and divided value in two textboxes. Either my javascript or Jquery isn't running. I get problem to get output while calculating the difference in Time and Divided value and finally multiplying with 100.

**View:**

```
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="supply" class="supply form-control" onchange="fill()"/>
            <span class="error">Supply required</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" id="POB" class="POB form-control" onchange="fill()"/>
            <span class="error">POB required</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="OCC" class="OCC form-control"/>
            <span class="error">OCC required</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" id="ETD" placeholder="00:00" class="ETD form-control" />
            <span class="error">ETD required</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" id="ATD" placeholder="00:00" class="ATD form-control" onchange="DifferenceTime()" />
            <span class="error">ATD required</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" id="Delay" placeholder="00:00" class="Delay form-control" />
            <span class="error">Delay required</span>
        </td>
```

and inside the Page at bottom i have created a function as:

```
function fill() {
            var total = (Number($('#POB').val()) / Number($('#supply').val()))*100;
            $('#OCC').val(total);
        }

function DifferenceTime(){
    var time= $('#ATD').val() -$('#ETD').val();
    $('#Delay').val(time);
    }
```

While calculating difference in time is as:
ATD: 00:20
ETD: 00:10 finally Delay should be 00:10. I need suitable help from all members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more than you were looking for. Hope it helps.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zyLa1xtw/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <table>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="supply" class="supply form-control" value="0" />
      <span class="error">Supply<em>*</em></span>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" id="POB" class="POB form-control" value="0" />
      <span class="error">POB<em>*</em></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="OCC" class="OCC form-control" />
      <span class="error">OCC<em>*</em></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="time" id="ETD" placeholder="00:00" class="ETD form-control" />
      <span class="error">ETD<em>*</em></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="time" id="ATD" placeholder="00:00" class="ATD form-control" />
      <span class="error">ATD<em>*</em></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="time" id="Delay" class="Delay form-control" />
      <span class="error">Delay<em>*</em></span>
    </td>
  </table>
  <em>*</em> - Required.
</div>
```

Making use of HTML5 input fields, you can help ensure that users are not entering unwanted data.

**JavaScript**

```
function fill(e) {
  var pob = parseInt($('#POB').val()),
    sup = parseInt($('#supply').val());
  if (pob === 0 || sup === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  $('#OCC').val((pob / sup) * 100);
}

function timeDiff(e) {
  if ($('#ATD').val() === "" || $('#ETD').val() === "") {
    return false;
  }
  var t1 = string2times($('#ATD').val()),
    t2 = string2times($('#ETD').val()),
    s1 = (t1.h * 3600) + (t1.m * 60) + (t1.s),
    s2 = (t2.h * 3600) + (t2.m * 60) + (t2.s),
    d = s1 - s2,
    sec = d % 60,
    min = Math.floor(d / 60),
    hour = Math.floor(d / 3600),
    format;

  console.log(t1, t2, s1, s2, d);
  if (d < 10) {
    $('#Delay').val("00:00:0" + d);
    return false;
  }
  if (d < 60) {
    $('#Delay').val("00:00:" + d);
    return false;
  }
  if (d < 3600) {
    min = Math.floor(d / 60);
    sec = d % 60;
    format = (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":";
    format += (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec);
    $('#Delay').val(format);
    return false;
  }
  sec = d % 60;
  min = Math.floor(d / 60);
  hour = Math.floor(d / 3600);
  format = (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour) + ":";
  format += (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":";
  format += (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec);
  $('#Delay').val(format);
  return false;
}

function string2times(s) {
  var elems = s.split(":");
  var time = {
    h: 0,
    m: 0,
    s: 0
  };
  if (elems.length == 3) {
    time.h = parseInt(elems[0]);
    time.m = parseInt(elems[1]);
    time.s = parseInt(elems[2]);
  } else {
    console.log("2 Count", elems);
    time.m = parseInt(elems[0]);
    time.s = parseInt(elems[1]);
  }
  return time;
}

$(function() {
  $(".supply, .POB").change(fill);
  $(".ATD").change(timeDiff);
});
```

Depending on how you're loading your JavaScript, your `onchange` callbacks may not identify the functions. You can easily move all this into one jQuery block and bind the events there.

In regards to calculating the difference between two times, you need to convert the times to seconds, do the math, and convert them back to a human readable result. I wasn't sure if you were working with `mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss` or `hh:mm.ss`, but I took a guess that users might enter `hh:mm:ss` or `mm:ss` and this can handle both.

The functions also check for empty fields or 0 values. Since you cannot divide by 0 and you don't want to subtract from 00:00, resulting ian negative delay value.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function brackets of onchange function. You have to rewrite onchange=DifferenceTime(). It will work, then you can check whether the logic is correct or not. Please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) for more.